# MySqli query: Column update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having difficulty to find the bug, it shows the query runs successfully but the database was not updated actually. The file got uploaded in correct directory though.

```
    $filetemp=$_FILES['dpfile']['tmp_name'];
        $filename=$_FILES['dpfile']['name'];
        //echo $filetemp;
        $filetype=$_FILES['dpfile']['type'];
        $filepath="../welcome/dp/".$dept."/".$filename;

        move_uploaded_file($filetemp, $filepath);


        $sql = "update teachers SET 
                                    filename='$filename',
                                    filepath='$filepath',
                                    filetype='$filetype'

                                    WHERE id='$edit_id'";

        $reslt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($reslt)
        {
                echo "file uploaded successfully";

        }
```

Comment: Side comment: you should look in to [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to remove the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: that was not the qn about SQL injection

Comment: Change `$reslt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` to `$reslt = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die mysqli_error($conn);` and check the output.

Comment: did the above but still no query error but table was not updated

Comment: I assume `$edit_id` is set?

Comment: oh yea....you are right@kerbholz...during page refresh it reset....my bad...thnak you for pointing out

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
echo $sql = "update teachers SET  filename='$filename', 
filepath='$filepath', filetype='$filetype'WHERE id='$edit_id'";
die();
```

to see if the query is correct